# O que pode ser feito para melhorar a minha função contagem?

Tags: python

Eu tenho esse programa que simula jogos de uma "loteria" estilo mega senna.
Funciona normal, mas gostaria de melhorar a minha função 'contagem' para apresentar todos os valores repetidos de cada número dentro de cada jogo.

Por exemplo: Para um total de 100 jogos eu obtive um total de x números 1, y números 2 e assim sucessivamente para todos os 60 números.

Eu fiz a codificação de uma forma meio infantil e gostaria de ajuda para melhora-lá, retirando as repetições exageradas e deixando o código mais limpo.

```
from random import randint

class Megasena(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quantidade_jogos = int(input(print('Quantos jogos deseja fazer ? : ')))
        self.todos_jogos = []

    def cria_jogo(self):
        x = 0
        while not x == self.quantidade_jogos:
            self.jogo = []
            for numeros in range(5):
                numeros = randint(1,60)
                if numeros not in  self.jogo:
                    self.jogo.append(numeros)
                    if len(self.jogo) == 5:
                        x += 1
                        #print(f'Jogo {x} = {self.jogo}')
                        self.todos_jogos.append(self.jogo)
        print(self.todos_jogos)
        return self.todos_jogos

    def contagem(self):
        self.todos_jogos = self.cria_jogo()
        numero1 = numero2 = numero3 = numero4 = numero5 = numero6 = numero7 = numero8 = numero9 = numero10 = 0

        for jogos in self.todos_jogos:
            numero1 += jogos.count(1)
            numero2 += jogos.count(2)
            numero3 += jogos.count(3)
            numero4 += jogos.count(4)
            numero5 += jogos.count(5)
            numero6 += jogos.count(6)
            numero7 += jogos.count(7)
            numero8 += jogos.count(8)
            numero9 += jogos.count(9)
            numero10 += jogos.count(10)


        print(f'A quantide de números 1 foi {numero1} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 2 foi {numero2} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 3 foi {numero3} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 4 foi {numero4} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 5 foi {numero5} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 6 foi {numero6} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 7 foi {numero7} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 8 foi {numero8} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 9 foi {numero9} \n'
              f'A quantide de números 10 foi {numero10} \n'
              )
        print(f'Para um total de {len(self.todos_jogos)} jogos')

Megasena().contagem()
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu método de contagem é, basicamente, um algoritmo de cálculo de [histograma](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histograma), que é capaz de calcular a frequência com a qual cada número se repete em um conjunto de números.

A biblioteca padrão [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) possui uma função chamada [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html), que é capaz de computar histogramas com grande eficiência.

Outra dica relevante, é a baixa eficiência do algoritmo de sorteio de dezenas no qual você usa uma técnica de [`força bruta`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_por_for%C3%A7a_bruta) para evitar sortear dezenas repetidas em uma mesma aposta.

O sorteio das dezenas pode ser feito de forma muito elegante e eficiente com a função [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Veja só como poderia ficar sua classe:

```
from random import sample
import numpy as np

class Megasena:
    def __init__(self, njogos):
        self.nbolinhas = 60
        self.ndezenas = 6
        self.njogos = njogos
        self.criar_jogos()

    def criar_jogos(self):
        self.jogos = [sample(range(1, self.nbolinhas + 1), self.ndezenas)
            for n in range(self.njogos)]
        return self.jogos

    def contagem(self):
        hist, _ = np.histogram([dezena for dezena in
            [jogo for jogo in self.jogos]], range(1,self.nbolinhas+2))
        return [(i,h) for i, h in enumerate(hist[1:],1)]

    def exibir_jogos(self):
        for i, jogo in enumerate(self.jogos,1):
            print(f'{i}. {sorted(jogo)}')

    def exibir_contagem(self):
        for dezena, frequencia in m.contagem():
            print(f'A quantide de números {dezena} foi {frequencia}')
        print(f'Para um total de {self.njogos} jogos.')


m = Megasena(int(input('Quantos jogos deseja fazer? ')))
m.exibir_jogos()
m.exibir_contagem()
```

Possível Saída:

```
Quantos jogos deseja fazer? 10
1. [6, 17, 23, 40, 49, 56]
2. [20, 24, 31, 44, 50, 57]
3. [27, 30, 37, 52, 57, 60]
4. [5, 25, 32, 35, 47, 58]
5. [19, 20, 22, 26, 32, 33]
6. [8, 10, 21, 33, 45, 53]
7. [13, 20, 26, 34, 44, 58]
8. [9, 23, 27, 32, 48, 60]
9. [4, 6, 24, 40, 48, 54]
10. [9, 16, 18, 25, 30, 37]
A quantide de números 1 foi 0
A quantide de números 2 foi 0
A quantide de números 3 foi 0
A quantide de números 4 foi 1
A quantide de números 5 foi 1
A quantide de números 6 foi 2
A quantide de números 7 foi 0
A quantide de números 8 foi 1
A quantide de números 9 foi 2
A quantide de números 10 foi 1
A quantide de números 11 foi 0
A quantide de números 12 foi 0
A quantide de números 13 foi 1
A quantide de números 14 foi 0
A quantide de números 15 foi 0
A quantide de números 16 foi 1
A quantide de números 17 foi 1
A quantide de números 18 foi 1
A quantide de números 19 foi 1
A quantide de números 20 foi 3
A quantide de números 21 foi 1
A quantide de números 22 foi 1
A quantide de números 23 foi 2
A quantide de números 24 foi 2
A quantide de números 25 foi 2
A quantide de números 26 foi 2
A quantide de números 27 foi 2
A quantide de números 28 foi 0
A quantide de números 29 foi 0
A quantide de números 30 foi 2
A quantide de números 31 foi 1
A quantide de números 32 foi 3
A quantide de números 33 foi 2
A quantide de números 34 foi 1
A quantide de números 35 foi 1
A quantide de números 36 foi 0
A quantide de números 37 foi 2
A quantide de números 38 foi 0
A quantide de números 39 foi 0
A quantide de números 40 foi 2
A quantide de números 41 foi 0
A quantide de números 42 foi 0
A quantide de números 43 foi 0
A quantide de números 44 foi 2
A quantide de números 45 foi 1
A quantide de números 46 foi 0
A quantide de números 47 foi 1
A quantide de números 48 foi 2
A quantide de números 49 foi 1
A quantide de números 50 foi 1
A quantide de números 51 foi 0
A quantide de números 52 foi 1
A quantide de números 53 foi 1
A quantide de números 54 foi 1
A quantide de números 55 foi 0
A quantide de números 56 foi 1
A quantide de números 57 foi 2
A quantide de números 58 foi 2
A quantide de números 59 foi 0
A quantide de números 60 foi 2
Para um total de 10 jogos.
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CelebratedBossyObjectcode)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção , essa forma que você fez ficou bem mais sofisticado !

Answer (score 1):

Em relação ao seu método **contagem** você poderia trabalhar com um mapping dos números de 1 a 60 em relação ao seus contadores, ou seja, basicamente o que eu to falando é que você poderia criar um dicionário dos números que podem ser sorteados como **key**, e o contador como o **value**, por exemplo, seu método ficaria assim:

```
def contagem_alt(self):
        self.todos_jogos = self.cria_jogo()
        mapping = {n:0 for n in range(1,61)}
        for jogo in self.todos_jogos:
            for number in jogo:
                mapping[number]+=1

        return mapping
```

Para a criação do dicionário eu utilizei um **dictionary comprehension**, se você ainda não conhece pode dar uma olhada aqui: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension

Além disso, para cada jogo que eu estou acessando no **self.todos_jogos**, eu faço mais um loop que passa pelos números sorteados daquele jogo, dessa forma eu posso diretamente o associar com o valor **key** do dicionário.

No final do método eu apenas retornei o mapping, mas se você quiser já imprimir diretamente, é só realizar um loop sob o dicionário e pronto.

**obs:** A função input() já recebe como argumento uma string que ele vai imprimir na tela no momento que ela for chamada, logo, você não deve fazer o **print()** dentro do input, e sim: **input('Quantos jogos deseja fazer:')**

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção , não sabia que dava para fazer dessa forma , vai me ajudar com outros programas também.